# How to use a switch properly in jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //set all logo images based on data returned from database
    var WinBack = $('div.jWinBackFrom').html();
    switch(WinBack) {
        case '1': //If database returns 1 : set Verizon FiOS logo
        $('div.jWinBackFrom').prepend('<img id="WinBackLogo" src="<?php echo site_url();?>/assets/images/verizon-fios-logo.jpg" />');
        break;

        case '2': //If database returns 2 : set DirecTV logo
        $('div.jWinBackFrom').prepend('<img id="WinBackLogo" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/directv-logo.jpg" />');
        break;

        case '3': //If database returns 3 : set DISH Network logo
        $('div.jWinBackFrom').prepend('<img id="WinBackLogo" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/dish-network-logo.jpg" />');
        break;
    }
```

On the page I have multiple `<div class="jWinBackFrom"><?php echo $optimum['cWinBackFrom'][$i]; ?></div>` inside of for loop.

So imagine an output of `<div class="jWinBackFrom">1</div>`,`<div class="jWinBackFrom">2</div>`,`<div class="jWinBackFrom">3</div>`,`<div class="jWinBackFrom">2</div>`,``` <div class="jWinBackFrom">1</div>``<div class="jWinBackFrom">3</div> ```,`<div class="jWinBackFrom">1</div>`
Basically all random. The jQuery needs to get the values from all of these DIV's and switch the numeric value with the associated image.

Can someone tell me if I'm doing this right (meaning proper method) is this the most efficient (probably not) So what is?

I need to repeat this process for many other fields. My theory is that it is faster to have the DB return a simple value like 1 and use jQuery to dynamically build the page.

I appreciate the help! THANK YOU!

Comment: I think I would just stick to having the backend output the appropriate images rather than having javascript run through the whole page replacing `id`s with images.  Unnecessary complexity for what seems like a minor gain (if any).

Comment: @JamesMontagne yes you're probably right. I could easily do this in PHP with just a SWITCH statement and get my desired output, however I am trying to learn jQuery. My second goal is making the page appear more dynamic. Killing 2 birds with 1 stone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about PHP, but I'd be inclined to add your options to an Array, and do a lookup of the index.

```
var choices = [
    "", // Apparently nothing at index 0
    '<img id="WinBackLogo" src="<?php echo site_url();?>/assets/images/verizon-fios-logo.jpg" />',
    '<img id="WinBackLogo" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/directv-logo.jpg" />',
    '<img id="WinBackLogo" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/dish-network-logo.jpg" />'
]

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.jWinBackFrom').html(function(i, htm) {
        return choices[htm];
    });
});
```

Comment: It's an easy enough fix, but this would leave the numeric values still within the divs when they should be replaced.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: You're right. I updated to use `.html()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In a situation / requirement like this, its usually best to create a *lookup hash*:

```
var hash = {
    1:   'verizon-fios-logo.jpg',
    2:   'directv-logo.jpg',
    3:   'dish-network-logo.jpg'
};
```

and then you could go like

```
$('div.jWinBackFrom').prepend('<img id="WinBackLogo" src="<?php echo site_url();?>/assets/images/"' + hash[ $('div.jWinBackFrom').html() ] + ' />');
```

As it turns out, in your case you could almost use a plain *Javascript Array* instead of a plain *Object*. You would just need to make indices start at `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: Except that there are multiple divs with that class.  You'll have to loop them.